# MySQL Port 3306 on VPS not visible from remote

Tags: mysql, port

Newbie here, migrating my site from a shared host to a name-based virtual host on a new virtual private server (Linode) running Ubuntu 16.04.  Apache is working.  I have installed MySQL and created an empty database.  I have no firewall (yet); iptables shows empty lists.

I have created a MySQL user named ‘jk’ with access from anywhere.  You can see it in this query result:

```
   mysql> select host, user from mysql.user;
   +-----------+------------------+
   | host      | user             |
   +-----------+------------------+
   | %         | jk               |
   | localhost | debian-sys-maint |
   | localhost | mysql.sys        |
   | localhost | root             |
   +-----------+------------------+
   4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and ‘netstat’ says that port 3306 is listening from anywhere (see first result):

```
  jk@bird:~$ netstat -an
  Active Internet connections (servers and established)
  Proto Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address      Foreign Address     State      
  tcp        0       0  127.0.0.1:3306     0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN     
  tcp        0       0  0.0.0.0:22         0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN     
  tcp        0     244  45.56.81.181:22    24.4.251.228:58915  ESTABLISHED
  tcp6       0       0  :::80              :::*                LISTEN     
  tcp6       0       0  :::22              :::*                LISTEN
```

All looks good on the Linode (to newbie me).

But not so good when I try to connect to it from my Mac.  Since DNS is still pointing to my old shared host, I specify my Linode server by its numerical IPv4 address.  When I ask the Port Scan feature of macOS’ Network Utility to scan for port 3306 on my Linode server, it finds nothing.  To verify that I am using this tool correctly, I scanned for ports 22 and 80 and it finds they are open as expected.  Likewise, it says port 3306 is open on my old shared host.

The MySQL client app (Sequel Pro) on my Mac corroborates the problem:

```
  MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on ‘45.56.81.181’ (61)
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misreading your netstat output.

`tcp        0       0  127.0.0.1:3306     0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN`

The port is bound only for use by [localhost](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Postfix-Cyrus-Web-cyradm-HOWTO/mysql-config.html) (Interprocess communication).

For a listener, "Local Address" indicates the address that is being listened on. since the only computer that can connect to 127.0.0.1 is the localhost, noone else can connect to the port. If the "local address" is 0.0.0.0 or 45.56.81.181 then a listener is bound to any address on any nic, or the LAN address respectively.

The Foreign Address is always 0.0.0.0:* for LISTENING ports (cause there is no other party on a listener). Foreign Address is only valid for existing connections (where the State is not 'LISTEN').

In your mysql config, you will have to configure it to listen on all interfaces (0.0.0.0) or on the LAN interface.

See here for documentation on configuring MySQL for network access: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html

Comment: Thank you, @Frank Thomas.  So, I added the following two lines to my mysql.cnf file:

`[mysqld]`
`bind-address=0.0.0.0`

and now netstat shows the “Local Address” as 0 0.0.0.0:3306
and now on my Mac, port 3306 is found, as desired.

Comment: I should probably point out, that exposing the MySQL port on a publicly hosted server is a very insecure configuration. perhaps the better approach is to set it back to local bindings, and use SSH tunnels to access mysqld or myPHPAdmin or whatever you are using. blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html